# Summing the distinct elements of query result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have following three tables representing a tree structure. Every row in `#A` is ancestor of zero or more rows in `#B`. Similarly every row in `#B` is ancestor of zero or more rows in `#C`. Table `#B` contains a column `value`. I need to find sum of `value` for all rows in `#B` whose belong to an input ancestor.

For example, consider following content of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #A (id varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE #B (id varchar(10), value int);
CREATE TABLE #C (id varchar(10), a_id varchar(10), b_id varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #A(id) VALUES ('A1'), ('A2');
INSERT INTO #B(id, value) VALUES('B1', 41), ('B2', 43), ('B3', 47);
INSERT INTO #C(id, a_id, b_id) VALUES('C1', 'A1', 'B1'), ('C2', 'A1', 'B1'),
                                     ('C3', 'A1', 'B2'), ('C4', 'A2', 'B3');
```

The above content represents following structure:

```
A1
|--- B1 (41)
|    |-------- C1
|    |-------- C2
|
|--- B2 (43)
     |-------- C3
A2
|--- B3 (47)
     |-------- C4
```

The parent-child relationship is weirdly defined. Table `#B` does not have its own column that says which row in table `#A` is its ancestor. All the mappings should be evaluated from table `#C`. Columns `a_id` and `b_id` in table `#C` designate grandparent and parent rows in table `#A` and `#B` respectively. If there is a row `Z` in `#C` where `a_id` is `X` and `b_id` is `Y`, then `X` is the ancestor of `Y` and `Y` is ancestor of `Z`. There will not be conflicting mappings in `#C`.

Problem Statement: For given id `A1`, find the sum of column `value` for all rows in `#B` whose parent is `A1`. Here there are two children of `A1`, `B1` with value `41` and `B2` with value `43` so we expect answer to be `84`.

If I do something like below:

```
SELECT SUM(#B.value) FROM #B
INNER JOIN #C ON #B.id = #C.b_id
INNER JOIN #A ON #C.a_id = #A.id
WHERE #A.id = 'A1'
```

I get `125` i.e. `41 + 41 + 43` instead of `84`, since two rows in `#A` have mapping `B1 -> C1`. I can write below query to get values associated with distinct rows in `#B` i.e. `41` and `43` but now I do not know how to sum the resultant values. Can I get the expected result without creating a temporary table?

```
SELECT MAX(#B.value) FROM #B
INNER JOIN #C ON #B.id = #C.b_id
INNER JOIN #A ON #C.a_id = #A.id
WHERE #A.id = 'A1'
GROUP BY #B.id;
```

I am not a SQL expert, so probably there might be a very simple solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need table #A here, because the IDs are in table #C and the values in table #B. That is all you need. No need to join either. Simply select the IDs needed from #C, then use them to select from #B.

```
select sum(value)
from #B
where id in
(
  select b_id
  from #C
  where a_id = 'A1'
);
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. As you said, table `#A` was not required. One more point for me to remember: `INNER JOIN` cannot replace `WHERE-IN` clause when we need to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
SELECT SUM(#B.value) 
FROM #B
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL FROM #C 
    INNER JOIN #A ON #C.a_id = #A.id
    WHERE #B.id = #C.b_id
    AND #A.id = 'A1'
)
```

Then you will only sum up the `#B` values where they exists in the other tables

The result will be: 84

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach.

```
SELECT SUM(#B.value) FROM #B
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT a_id, b_id FROM #C
  ) temp
ON
temp.b_id=#B.ID
WHERE temp.a_id='A1';
```

This has the advantage that you can change the `WHERE temp.a_id='A1'` to `GROUP BY temp.a`